# no indexes in Indexing Manager

Tags: solr

I've recently installed a fresh local instance of Sitecore 10.3 XP0, and I've encountered an unusual issue. When I attempt to populate a Solr schema or rebuild indexes, the only indexes that appear are 'Local indexes'
[image: Indexing Manager]

[image: Solr Schema]

This is the first time I've faced this problem, and I even tried a complete reinstallation of Sitecore 10.3 XP0 and Solr 8.11.2, but the issue persists. It's important to note that I'm using Solr with the HTTPS protocol, and I can see all indexes correctly and there are no errors in logs. When I check the Sitecore logs, I don't find any error messages. The logs contain the following information:

```
20180 12:50:47 INFO  Warming and Caching your search indexes
20180 12:50:47 INFO  /******* Warming Queries ********/
20180 12:50:47 INFO  /*************************/
```

How could I potentially fix this problem?
Thanks for any information you could provide (:

Comment: 1) check solr url is correct in conn string, 2) check your solr configs and ensure the core names match those in solr dashboard - if necessary double check using showconfig.aspx that solr patches are doing what you expect and still match the cores

Comment: 1. Connection string is correct 2. Everything is matching

Answer (score 0):

You should really check the main log file, not the Search log. This usually happens when either

- Solr is not accessible at all,
- Solr certificate is not correct or not trusted
- or Solr wasn't ready when your CM started.

In any of those cases, you won't most probably get any error messages when Sitecore is already running, only at the beginning you will get one of those:

```
ERROR Unable to connect to Solr at [https://solr.local/solr]
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrConnectors.Exceptions+SolrConnectorException
Message: Unable to connect to Solr at [https://solr.local/solr]
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrConnectors.SolrConnector.VerifyConnection(String solrAddress)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrConnectors.SolrConnector.Initialize(String solrAddress)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.InitializeSolr()
```

or

```
ERROR Unable to connect to [https://solr.local/solr], Core: [sitecore_master_index]
Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/sitecore_master_index/schema. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

Source: SolrNet
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrNetExtension.Impl.SolrBasicServerEx`1.GetManagedSchema()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.InitializeSchema()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.InitializeSolr()
```

or warning

```
WARN  IsOnline: Test connection has failed with an exception. 
    Type: 'SolrConnectionException', 
    Message: 'The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.'
```

Comment: I didn't find any exceptions, but what I see: `ManagedPoolThread #1 14:37:18 WARN  IsOnline: Test connection has failed with an exception. Type: 'SolrConnectionException', Message: 'The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.'`

Comment: As I wrote in my answer - looks like your Solr certificate is not trusted. You created it on your own as self-signed certificate? Have you added it to Trusted cert store?

Comment: Yeah, I have created the certificate on my own and added to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities. It's kind of odd that from the installation he could establish connection without any errors.